# how to remove zip , fax , company field from checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I want to ask how to remove tax, company, middle name, zip postal code from checkout one page

Magento 1.9

Answer (score 3):

You can remove fax,company and zip/postal code from below phtml file.

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml
```

middle name from -

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\widget\name.phtml
```

Best way to do it is first copy all phtml template files to your custom theme then remove it.

Comment: Are you sure that it works? you thought a little about a validations ?, you risk to have a downvotes with this solution !

Comment: you mean remove the company code from the file?

Comment: yes remove Company field from file.
And make query in table as Prince said.
Update eav_attribute table where attribute_code = 'postcode' to set is_required to 0 instead of 1

Comment: thanks for your help, but it didn't remove :(

Comment: make sure you are changing in your custom theme file.

Answer (score 0):

For the `Company` and `Fax`, you have to comment the fields in :

```
app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

For `Zip`: you comment the **zip field** in the three paths mentionned above plus this :

Update `eav_attribute` table where `attribute_code = 'postcode'` to set **is_required** to `0` instead of `1`

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by comment?

Comment: You put it in a comment <?php /* the field */ ?> instead of remove

Comment: thanks for your help, but it didn't remove :(